# I'm a newers for pgfplots, why the code with differ charts in my two computers, but the lines look so differ?

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex

I try to generate my chart in latex using the same code(named glauber-thickness2.tex)  in my Laptop after I tpye "pdflatex -shell-escape glauber-thickness2.tex" in cmd.exe,

it generate glauber-thickness2.pdf, but the line is too thick, so I run it in my desktop computer and my classmate's computer, the chart's line is thin which's just I need, Anybody know how to fix the differ, why the same code with different lines? thank you very much!:

iso: windows10 64bit,CTeX_2.9.2.164_Full.exe, texmakerwin32_install.exe

The code is following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figures/]

\begin{document}

\tikzsetnextfilename{glauber-thickness2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={Thickness function of tranverse positon $r_\perp$},
    legend style={
        legend cell align=left,
        at={(0.08,0.98)},
        anchor=north west
    },
    scaled ticks=true,
    xticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/precision=0,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    },
    yticklabel style={
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
    },
    xlabel={\Large{Tranverse position [$r_\perp$]}},
    xmin=0, xmax=12, minor x tick num=4,
    ylabel={\Large{Thickness function[$T_A(r_\perp)$]}},
    ymin=0, ymax=3, minor y tick num=4,
]

\addplot[color=violet]
    table{data/out5au.dat};

\addplot[color=red]
    table{data/out5cu.dat};

\addplot[color=olive]
    table{data/out5pb.dat};

\legend{
    \tiny{Au},
    \tiny{Cu},
    \tiny{Pb},
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

The first png generate from laptop with very thick line, looks bad,
[image]

The second png generate fome desktop with thin line, looks good,
[image]

Comment: I do not think that the first picture is the result of this code. There are markers drawn for each pair of coordinates in your data file and there are dashed and dotted lines instead of solides. Maybe you are using `\addplot+[...]` for your first picture or you enable markers in the plot options?

Comment: Thanks esdd @esdd, you are right, I think I have delete the plus before copy the code to this Question, So I try to delete the '+'  and run the code, Waul, the line turns to thin and no marks, ok , I think '\addplot+[color=red]' will give random marks default event no '[no marks]' for it, I should type \addplot[color=red] or \addplot+[color=red, no marks], Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `\addplot+[...]`. Remove the `+` und use `\addplot[...]`.

With the `+` the normal cycle list is used and the options in the optional argument are added. Note that the normal cycle list uses marks.

Without the `+` only the given options are used.

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=50]
\addplot{2};% cycle list options are used
\addplot[]{-2};% no options from the cycle list
\addplot[violet]{x};% no options from the cycle list
\addplot+[olive]{-x};% color olive is added to the the cycle list options
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much@esdd, I had fixed the problem, But how can I tag the Question in tex.stackexchange.com with "fixed alreadly" :) ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour.